# Project VBA File_Subs not displaying

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a number of modules written in MS Project that are part of a template for our project managers.  Randomly, a user will indicate that the needed macros are not availabe.  When I have them share the screen with me, I will notice that the project file they have open does not display at all in the visual basic screen.  Only the ProjectGlobal is listed. In the image below you can see what I would expect to see with the VBAProject (MO2206-....)  However, when the user opens the visual basic screen, it is missing.  This appears to be completely random. I have them open previous versions from SharePoint, and it displays fine.  It diplays other project files they open as well.   Even more odd, when I open the same file, I can see the file and modules.  What am I missing that would cause this?  Users are also enabling macros in security settings, etc. Everyting works as it should for about 95% of my users.  Those that experience this have it happen once every month or so where we then take their project schedule and copy/paste it into the base template which fixes the issue. Any help is much appreciated!

[image: VisualBasic Image]

Comment: Maybe the user has only Execute access and not Read access to the .MPP?  This seems very much like some kind of security/access problem.

Comment: You might try posting this question to the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com) site as there are more Project users there.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered the same about security but it is so random for the user in that they can one day and then a week later they no longer can view/execute.  Then I update and they can again.   Ill post in the Project Management section, thanks again!